# How to add policy to restrict google cloud function invoker using Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-functions, terraform

I am trying to create a ServiceAccount that has restricted access to invoke a single cloud function.

```
resource "google_service_account" "service_account" {
  account_id   = "service-account-id"
  display_name = "Service Account"
}

data "google_iam_policy" "invoker" {
  binding {
    role = "roles/cloudfunctions.invoker"
    members = [
      "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.service_account.email}",
    ]
    condition {
      expression =  "resource.name == projects/project_name/locations/region/functions/function_name"
      title = foo
    }
  }
}

resource "google_cloudfunctions2_function_iam_policy" "binding" {
  cloud_function = "projects/project_name/locations/region/functions/function_name"
  project        = var.common.project_id
  location       = var.common.default_region
  policy_data    = data.google_iam_policy.invoker.policy_data
}
```

However when I apply this change I get an error.

> module.handler-build.google_cloudfunctions2_function_iam_policy.binding: Creating...
> ╷
> │ Error: Error setting IAM policy for cloudfunctions2 function "projects/project_name/locations/region/functions/function_name": googleapi: Error 400: Invalid argument: 'An invalid argument was specified. Please check the fields and try again.'

I would try to call `google_cloudfunctions2_function_iam_binding` or `google_cloudfunctions2_function_iam_member` but they don't have condition expression that I can use. It is important to add the condition so this service account cannot call other cloud functions.

How can I add invoker policy to the service account?

Answer (score 0):

For v2 cloud functions you need to create the IAM binding on the resultant Cloud Run instance instead when using Terraform. You also need to use the roles/run.invoker role.

You can reference the parameters from the Cloud Function terraform resource but using the google_cloud_run_v2_service_iam_binding resource. Something like:

```
resource "google_cloud_run_v2_service_iam_binding" "binding" {
  location = google_cloudfunctions2_function.default.location
  project  = google_cloudfunctions2_function.default.project
  name     = google_cloudfunctions2_function.default.name
  role     = "roles/run.invoker"
  members = [
    "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.service_account.email}"
  ]
}
```

There appears to be a bug in the provider as I don't think the google_cloudfunctions2_function_iam_binding works correctly!